# Why Excel doesn't ask(prompt) to Save the file which is modified while closing

Tags: microsoft-excel, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

This is what happens,

1. I open an Excel (2013) file (of any kind)
2. Make changes to the file.
3. Close it.

   - Before, it used to ask if I want to save the file sine it's modified.
   - Now, it closes the file WITHOUT saving the changes straight away. BAM!

Comment: What version of excel are you using, are there any macros or add-ins that are loaded.  You could try closing it using vba to see if it would ask you then `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` then `
Application.Quit`.  [Another Similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438746/excel-doesnt-prompt-to-save-unsaved-files-on-application-quit)

Comment: 2012. I figured out the exact same thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you guys do any programing using Visual Studio which handles excel files or even use an executable file which does so.

In my case, I was using this piece of code

```
app.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

which I didn't turn it back to **true** after I was finished with saving the excel
file inside the code and I was experiencing the this problem. 
All I did was to turn it back to the **True** value again at the end of save inside my code.

*The interesting thing is that, if somebody would use the software I developed (at start) and surely doesn't have an access to the source code, he would suffer from the same problem while using Excel and he couldn't do anything about it. I am curious if there is any way to trigger this value back on for excel other than commanding him to do so from a code being developed.*

Comment: Excel has a number of defaults built-in, including the display alerts. Once you code something that changes that default, it will not revert unless you tell it to. That is what you want to have happen. If it didn't work like that, programmers would have a difficult time finding out why their code wasn't working. Recap and General rule: if you turn it off, turn it back on (and vice versa). And don't forget to turn things back on, even when there is an error that stops normal execution of your code.

Comment: @GuitarThrower, I agree with that. I am also interested in knowing that if there is method to return all those settings back to normal?

Comment: And honestly I am not sure why my question got down voted. i had this problem and I simply couldn't find the answer for it and I totally went with guess work to be able to fix it. Wouldn't this question be useful at all?

Comment: There is a method to return them to normal. You reverse your original code. There is no return all, because one person's "normal" is not going to be the same as another's idea of normal.

Comment: I have a feeling it got downvoted because you failed to mention in the question that you had code at all, let alone code that got rid of alerts. Or, that it may be a duplicate as indicated by another comment on your question. Always going to get downvotes if there are other questions out there with answers. Part of the SuperUser experience is that people really like those who have done homework and ask specific questions rather than present very vague issues.